Return the address of last non-empty string cell
I've been researching this for a bit and can't find a solution.  Thanks for the help.
Without using VBA, I'd like to:
Return the cell address of that last cell in a column with a numerical value in it.

The problem is, the data is populated with a formula that leaves empty strings (it returns "") instead of actual empty cells.  I've researched that there is no way to write a formula that can return a truly empty cell.

The ROWS function counts empty strings as values, so I need a way to use an if statement in conjunction with ROWS and ADDRESS to return the cell address of the last cell in a column with a numerical value.



To return the address of the last numerical entry in Row 1:
=ADDRESS(1,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(1:1),COLUMN(1:1)))

or, in more recent versions of Excel:
=ADDRESS(1,XMATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1:1),0,-1))

Edit: You have changed your question and are now asking for the last numerical entry in a column:
Minor changes in formulas
=ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(A:A),ROW(A:A)),COLUMN(A:A))

or
=ADDRESS(XMATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(A:A),,-1),COLUMN(A:A))

Edit2: I see that your title mentions a string cell but your question text mentions a numeric cell
for text cells:
=ADDRESS(XMATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1/IFERROR(LEN(A:A),0)),,-1),COLUMN(A:A))


Thank you, this is the answer for last in a row, the other is for the last in a column - both helpful.

@user26707498 you had initially asked for the last entry in a row. Now you have edited your question for the last numerical entry in a column. Please see my edit for the appropriate change.

@user26707498 further modifications since I see your title refers to strings even though your question text refers to number values. You really need to be consistent in how you formulate a questions.

This formula returns the last non empty cell in column A. It counts Error values also as non-empty.
=ADDRESS(MAX(IF(IFERROR(LEN(A:A),1)>0,ROW(A:A),0)),COLUMN(A:A))
If Error values no need to count then use this:
=ADDRESS(MAX(IF(IFERROR(LEN(A:A),0)>0,ROW(A:A),0)),COLUMN(A:A))

Thank you, this is the answer for last in a column, the other is for the last in a row - both helpful.
